# ERROR: could not get unknown property 'plugin' for root project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am trying to build LineageOS' trebuchet launcher. After updating protobuf plugin I managed to get rid of some errors. But after several tries I can not handle this error:

> Could not get unknown property 'plugin' for root project
> 'android_packages_apps_Trebuchet-lineage-16.0' of type
> org.gradle.api.Project.

This is my first time editing code from Github. Please help.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.13'
    }
}
apply plugin 'com.android.application'
apply plugin 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.13'


final String SUPPORT_LIBS_VERSION = '28.0.0'


android {

    defaultConfig {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

*There is a lot more code after this, didn't seem important so didn't add. Let me know if it's needed*

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

with a colon.